# Meteor Up load balancer

Tags: nginx, meteor, load-balancing, meteor-up

My meteor application is deployed with [mup.js](http://meteor-up.com/docs.html) 
I would like to use balance loader for several reasons. (No downtime deployment, better user experience) 
In the docs. there is a `Swarm` what makes a cross server load balancing, but I would have separated app containers at the same server. And they just running on different ports, what NGINX balancing

**Status:** Have started different app containers at the same server, but can not configure the `nginx`.

Having 2x mup file (1. mup.js, mup-support.js) They are pretty same, but the support runs only the app container, and connects it to the db.

mup.js:

```
  proxy: {
    domains: "domain.com",
    nginxServerConfig: "./staging.nginx.conf",
    loadBalancing: true,
    ssl: {
      // ... config
    }
  }
```

staging.nginx.conf:

```
upstream pass_servers {
  server container1
  server container2
}

server {
        server_name domain.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/domain.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://pass_servers.com;
        }
}
```

**Result:**  crashed `nginx`

**Question:**  Is the logic fine, or should I go in a different way? If the logic is fine, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Comment: yep, I had to create a new mup.js `mup-balance-1.js` with `app.env.PORT: <your port>`. In the `mup.js` I had to define: `proxy.loadBalancing: true`. `mup setup && mup reconfig`. Then deploy the balance-1: `mup --config mup-balance-1.js --settings original-settings.json deploy --verbose`.
Then at the server I had to add the ip/localhost: <your port> to the upstream manually. Would be great to automatize this step.

Comment: Would you mind creating an answer for your question then? It may be helpful for others who search for this issue.